# Can Entity Framework cascade deletes of 1:many for same record types?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have the following model:

```
public class Organization
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public Organization? Parent { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Organization>? Children { get; private set; }
}
```

Now I know, but obviously the database does not, that there will be no cycles in this parent-child set of collections. (An organization is a Country, State, or County.)

As I understand it, SQL Server (my underlying repository) sees the possibility of cycles and throws an exception if asked to perform a cascading delete. Is this correct?

In which case, is my best bet to do:

```
public class OrganizationConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Organization>
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Organization> builder)
    {
        builder.HasMany(x => x.Children).WithOne(x => x.Parent).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
    }
}
```

And then overload my `DbContext.SaveChangesAsync` and in that, walk children, grandchildren, etc. when an Organization is deleted and delete this (grand)children?

Sample program illustrating the problem - [TestModelHasChildren.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/93cydtv7bs3noco/TestModelHasChildren.zip?dl=1).